# Document exchanged format in differen CMS

Tags: content-management-system, format, alfresco, document

Is there any document exchange format for metadata among CMS? 
For example, between Sharepoint and Alfresco, or Alfresco and Documentum?

Comment: Did you try [CMIS](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/cmis/)?

Answer (score 1):

I've been building a CMS and couldn't find a commonly accepted standard for content metadata. I decided to use the approach NestaCMS did by simply placing it at the top of the document: http://nestacms.com/docs/creating-content/metadata-reference

And then filtering it out when published.